# text placement automatic and in relation to other text

Tags: html, css, text, positioning

I have a bunch of divs with content inside of them, and I want the text to automatically adjust! For instance, in div one the length and size of the text might vary compared to the other divs, and I want to set one css rule to make sure that the text looks structured regardless of those attributes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="#info-1">
<h4>Subtitle</h4>
<h1>Title</h1>
<h3>Subtitle</h3>

</div>

<div id="#info-2">
<h4>Subtitle</h4>
<h1>Title</h1>
<h3>Subtitle</h3>
</div>

<div id="#info-3">
<h4>Subtitle</h4>
<h1>Title</h1>
<h3>Subtitle</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#info-1, #info-2, #info-3{
                           position:absolute;
                           top:0px;
                           margin-top: 75px;
                           margin-left:350px;     
                           float: left
                         }

#info-1 h3, #info-2 h3, #info-3 h3
                                  {
                                   position:absolute; 
                                   top: 105px;
                                   left: 130px;
                                  }

#info-1 h4, #info-2 h4, #info-3 h4
                                  {
                                   position:absolute; 
                                   top:40px; 
                                   left:75px; 
                                  }

#info-1, #info-2, #info-3, #info-4{
                   background-color: lightgrey;     
                   width:300px; height:175px;
                                  }

#info-1 h1, #info-2 h1,#info-3 h1
        {
        position:absolute;top: 55px; left:60px;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        }
```

Comment: for starters, you can take the `#` out of the `<div id='#info-1'>` etc. apart from that, i can't really tell what you are trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here - maybe you could try to explain again? What do you mean by "structured"?

Meanwhile, I would remove the hashes from your id attributes of your example or you'll not see any styling at all.